# Adding a new variable to a .mat file using the Python package hdf5storage

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5, hdf5storage

Is it possible to add a new variable to a .mat file (v7.3) using the Python package  [hdf5storage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage/0.1.3)?

---

Example:

I wrote in Matlab:

```
test = {'Hello', 'world!'; 'Good', 'morning'; 'See', 'you!'};
save('data.mat', 'test', '-v7.3') % v7.3 so that it is readable by h5py
```

[image]

In Python I would like to add a new variable to `data.mat`. How can I do so, to achieve something like:

[image]

I tried:

```
import hdf5storage # get code on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage/0.1.3
import numpy as np

matcontent = {}
matcontent[u'some_numbers'] = np.array([10, 50, 20]) # each key must be a unicode string
hdf5storage.write(matcontent, '.', 'data.mat', matlab_compatible=True)
```

but it overwrites `data.mat` instead of adding a new variable.

Comment: Does it have to be done with hdf5storage? Scipy also offers this functionality.

Comment: scipy only supports the Version 5 format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new data, then writing that new data to a file.  That overwrites the file.  You need to load the original `.mat` file, append to it, then save again.

```
import hdf5storage
import numpy as np

matcontent = hdf5storage.loadmat('data.mat')
matcontent[u'some_numbers'] = np.array([10, 50, 20])
hdf5storage.savemat('data.mat', matcontent)
```

Then in Matlab

```
>> whos -file data.mat
      Name              Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

      some_numbers      1x3                24  int64              
      test              3x2               730  cell
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I know this is not possible. The answer provided by TheBlackCat is not really applicable as you are rewriting you file. I tend to have really big matlab files which I won't normally want to read completely and instead read or write selectively. That's the big advantage (together with referencing) of the underlying HDF5 format used in the .mat files. The python package hdf5storage is still in 0.xx version so I suppose this will come in future versions.